# Finding the gradient of $f(x) := \ln \left( 1 + e^{-ab^Tx} \right)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, scalar-fields

> Given $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let the scalar field $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$ f(x) := \ln \left( 1 + e^{-ab^Tx} \right)$$ Find the gradient of $f$.

---

I'm attempting to apply the chain rule here but I'm finding it difficult to apply. The chain rule as I know it goes like:

for $h(x) = f(g(x))$

$$ \nabla h(x) = D f(x)^T \nabla g(f(x)) $$
where $f :\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, $g: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $h : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

So I set, $g(x) = 1 + e^{-ab^Tx}$ and $f(y) = \ln(y)$. I'm not sure where to go with this now. My guess is that,
$$Df(x)^T = \frac{1}{1+e^{-ab^Tx}}$$ and $$ \nabla g(f(x)) = -abe^{-ab^Tx}$$ So the final answer should be $$ \nabla f(x) = \frac{-abe^{-ab^Tx}}{e^{-ab^Tx}}$$

Is this correct? If wrong, any help to find the right answer would be appreciated. ${{}}$

Comment: You have written $x \in \mathbb R$. I think it should be $x \in \mathbb R^{n}$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! In addition to the [important @KaviRamaMurthy's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2921094/finding-gradient-of-a-multi-variable-function#comment6034626_2921094) the expression "$f(x) = \ln(1 + e^{-ab^Tx})$" **isn't** a multivariable function, since only depends on $x$. So in that case you *don't* have to find a gradient, but the derivative. If not, please correct your grammar, so we can help you better.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy corrected, thanks!

Comment: @manooooh Since $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ I thought it belongs to multi variable calculus. Isn't it? If not, what do you call these calculations?

Comment: @manooooh Surely $b^T x \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to think of the chain rule with the notation

$$ D (f \circ g)(x) = Df(g(x)) \circ Dg(x) $$
(See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions) on the chain rule. $Df(x)$ means the Jacobian matrix of $f$ at the point $x$)

I would decompose your function as $F(x) = f(g(x))$ where $g(x) = b^T x$ and $f(y) = \ln(1+e^{ay})$. Since $g(x) = b_1x_1  + \cdots b_n x_n$, then $Dg(x) = \nabla g(x) = b$. Also, $Df(y) = \frac{df}{dy} = \frac{ae^{ay}}{1+e^{ay}}$. So I think you get

$$ \nabla F(x) = \frac{ae^{ab^Tx}}{1+e^{ab^Tx}} \, b $$

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\a{\alpha} \def\b{\lambda} \def\l{\lambda}
\def\bb{\l^{-1}} \def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Define a new scalar variable
$$\eqalign{
&\b = \o+ e^{-\a b^Tx} \\
&\LR{\b-\o} = e^{-\a b^Tx}
 &\qiq d\b &= e^{-\a b^Tx}\LR{-\a b^Tdx} \\ &&& = \LR{\o-\b}\LR{\a b^Tdx} \\
}$$
and use it to rewrite the function and calculate the gradient
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \log(\b) \\
df &= \bb\,d\b \\
 &= \a\bb\LR{\o-\b}\,b^Tdx \\
\grad{f}{x}
 &= \a\bb\LR{\o-\b}b \\
 &= \LR{\frac{-\a e^{-\a b^Tx}}{\o+e^{-\a b^Tx}}}b \\
}$$